# Hide menuBar on click icefaces

Tags: icefaces

I know icefaces has a "displayOnClick" parameter so that it will display when clicked on.  However, clicking on it again does not hide it.  You have to click off.  Does anyone know if there's a way to make it hide when clicked on again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: this can only be done in ace 3.x.  To do it otherwise, you need to use javascript.